# Concern to work with ASP.net Core 2.1 MVC with legacy application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a new module into an old legacy ASP.net webForms project.

Currently, I do not have access to the code. The client wants us to make a stand-alone application, for now, once they're happy, they will merge the module into their existing  ASP.net web forms application.

I am planning to make this module in asp.net core 2.1 MVC using Entity framework.

Two queries :

1) Would the new ASP.net core MVC 2.1 module be compatible with old ASP.net webforms web app. made in older.Net Framework?

2) Is it feasible to keep the new module made in ASP.net core MVC with the existing modules made in ASP.net Webforms?

Answer (score 1):

> > Would the new ASP.net core MVC 2.1 module be compatible with old ASP.net webforms web app. made in older.Net Framework?

From a codebase persective, MVC and Webforms are completely different. You can't integrate them into one project. Possibly two projects in one solution

> > Is it feasible to keep the new module made in ASP.net core MVC with the existing modules made in ASP.net Webforms?

Yes. They would need to be published through different web applications. This could be transparent to the user because all the activity is through URL's